# Переменные php в json

Tags: php, json

Доброго времени суток. Нужно как-то вставить переменные php в эти поля, как это сделать? Пожалуйста, подскажите

```
    <html>
<head><title>GET ЗАПРОСЫ</title></HEAD>
<FORM id="obratnai_cvaz" METHOD="GET" ACTION="">
<?php
$danie1=$_GET['a'];
$danie3=$_GET['b'];                        
$danie2='{
   "data": "dbfriends",
    "friends": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Andrew",
            "city": "Moscow",
            "contacts": {
                "mobile": "здесь, например, должна быть переменная $danie1",
                "email": "здесь, например, должна быть переменная $danie1",
                "skype": "здесь, например, должна быть переменная $danie1"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "40.7143528",
            "city": "Kiev",
            "contacts": {
                "mobile":"*здесь, например, должна быть переменная $danie1" ,
                "email": "здесь, например, должна быть переменная $danie3",
                "skype": "здесь, например, должна быть переменная $danie1"
            }
        }
    ]
}';                               
$fh=fopen("/storage/ssd1/822/2911822/public_html/1.php","w") or die("He удалось открыть файл") ;          
fwrite($fh,$danie2);      
fwrite($fh,$danie1);
fwrite($fh,$danie3);     
fclose($fh);             
?>
</FORM>
</html>
```

Comment: Откуда изначально эти данные? Из файла? Из массива?

Comment: полный код добавил в вопрос

Comment: "mobile":"'. $danie1.'" , "email":"'.$danie3.'", "skype": '.$skype.',

Comment: @Даниил, как можно такое советовать? `$danieX` прямым текстом - пользовательский ввод...

Comment: @vp_arth а чеб и нет

Answer (score 1):

Сформируйте нужную структуру из php-массивов, потом генерируйте json, с помощью `json_encode`:

```
$d1 = 'd1';
$d2 = 'd2';

$data = array(
  'data' => 'dbfriends',
  'friends' => array(),
);
$data['friends'][] = array(
    'id' => '1',
    'contacts' => array('skype' => $d1),
);
$data['friends'][] = array(
    'id' => '2',
    'contacts' => array('skype' => $d2),
);

$d3 = json_encode($data);

echo $d3;
```